# IFormFile is always null when receiving file from console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have my WebAPI method ready to accept file as parameter shown below:
(e.g. URI "https://localhost:44397/api/uploadfile"

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class UploadFileController : ControllerBase
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
    }
}
```

Am using console app to send file to this API method, below is my code:

```
    public static void Send(string fileName)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44397");
            var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var index = fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\");
            var fn = fileName.Substring(index + 1);
            fs.Position = 0;

            var contentfile = new StreamContent(fs);
            content.Add(contentfile, "file", fn);
            var result = client.PostAsync("/api/uploadfile", content).Result;
        }
    }
```

I also checked with other clients (e.g. Postman) and it failed there too (so it seems like an issue in the server-side, rather than the console app).

Not sure what am I doing wrong here. Whenever I check my WebAPI method file parameter is always null.

Can anyone help me finding solution to this? I tried searching blogs to no avail. I may be doing something naive here.

Comment: You need to isolate whether the problem is in the client (console) side or server (web api) side. To confirm that, please let us know if you are able to post file information from other clients (e.g. web browser or Postman)? If not, put the console app to one side and don't touch it until you get another client working. Then come back to the console app.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I can see files in my Request.Form.Files Property but my parameter IFormFile is always null. Thats where I was trying to fix. Seems the issue is with the [ApiController] attribute. When I removed it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I made it Working. It must be a bug in microsoft or they may have change the way things works from .net core 2.1 for ApiController.

I changed my WebApi method to the following and voila it worked.

Note: removed ApiController and it worked. Microsoft should document this.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OCRController : ControllerBase
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
    }
}
```

It may help someone who is struggling like me.

Comment: Great work solving your issue! I am glad my comment on your question helped you narrow down the cause as being on the server-side rather than on the client-side. I'll edit your question to make that clearer for other people reading it in future.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question still stands but for anyone who wants to retain the [ApiController] attribute there is a workaround as described in [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8311) GitHub thread.

Basically, try to expand the [FromForm] attribute like so...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OCRController : ControllerBase
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try explicit content type to your `MultipartFormDataContent`

```
var contentfile = new StreamContent(fs);
contentfile.Headers.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
content.Add(contentfile, "file", fn);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not work. I tried with the code, contentfile.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"); Getting IFormFile still as null.