# IFormFile file is allways null at my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

When I send from Postman a file against my controller, the object *file* is allways null.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FileUploadController : BaseApiController<FileUploadController>
{
    public FileUploadController(ILogger<FileUploadController> logger) : base(logger) { }

    [HttpPost]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[file.Length]);
```

At Postman I set POST https://localhost:5001/api/FileUpload, no Params, no Header, Body to form-data and key: file, value I choose a file. Send.

At my breakpoint in the code above last line the object *file* is allways *null*. **How do I get the file into my controller?**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294830/iformfile-is-always-null-when-receiving-file-from-console-app

Comment: Do you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: this link might be help you :[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895523/asp-core-webapi-test-file-upload-using-postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895523/asp-core-webapi-test-file-upload-using-postman)

Comment: @SalahAkbari This link does not help. I guess this problem is fixed from Microsoft already.

Comment: @koviroli I use form-data at Postman. Please look at the screenshot above. But do I need to set it some where else?

Comment: @VikasShinde I've been setting it like described in your link. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**The first solution:**
You must also enter the name of the input argument in the postman `form-data` as follows if you want to use the `IFormFile` argument:
[image]

**The second solution:**
Get the file from `HttpContext` using .net Core 2.X:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
        {
            IFormFile file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a property of type `IFormFile` in the class, like:

```
public class FileData
{
    public IFormFile file { get; set; } 
}
```

add that class as input parameter.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] FileData fileData)
{   
   // fileData.file 
}
```

you will get attached file in `fileData.file`

Comment: There I get a 415 "Unsupported Media Type".

Comment: make sure that you are sending data in form from postman with `key :file `

Comment: Yes. form-data. Key: file, value: a small choosen file

Comment: Content-Type should be multipart/form-data

Comment: How to set multipart?

Comment: Yes thanks. I saw this. Actually I set form-data what I did.

Comment: check your Key should be `file` not `File`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem was the spelling ***F***ile instead of ***f***ile at the Postman Body key, as KDM mentioned.